# (De)Serialization XML to Object c#, without wrapping class and best practice

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

We have an XML that looks like:

```
<Contract Contract="123">
    <Contractbegin Contractbegin="20130301" />
    <Contractend Contractend="20130331" />
</Contract>
```

The classes looks like

```
public class Contract
{
     [XmlElement("Contractbegin")]
     public Contractbegin Contractbegin {get; set;}

     [XmlElement("Contractend")]
     public Contractend Contractend {get; set;}
}

public class Contractbegin
{
     [XmlAttribute("Contractbegin")]
     public String value {get;set;}
}

public class Contractend
{
     [XmlAttribute("Contractend")]
     public String value {get;set;}
}
```

I have just two questions:

Is it possible to deserialize without using wrapping classes Contractend and Contractbegin?

Is it possible create a common class for that? Cause Contractbegin and -end looks almost the same..I´m pretty sure that has to be a way to do it more...general =D

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

The xml before was just an example, this is how really looks like:

```
<Vorgang Vorgang="Vorgang1">
    <Lieferrichtung Lieferrichtung="Z07" />
    <Vertragsbeginn Vertragsbeginn="20130301" />
    <Vertragsende Vertragsende="20130331" />
    <Bilanzierungsbeginn Bilanzierungsbeginn="20130301" />
    <Bilanzierungsende Bilanzierungsende="20130331" />
    <Netznutzungsvertrag Netznutzungsvertrag="E02" />
    <Zahler_der_Netznutzung Zahler_der_Netznutzung="E10" />
    <Bilanzierungsgebiet Bilanzierungsgebiet="11YV00000000080S">
        <ID ID="11YV00000000080S" />
    </Bilanzierungsgebiet>
    <Regelzone Regelzone="10YDE-VE-------2">
        <ID ID="10YDE-VE-------2" />
    </Regelzone>
    <Bilanzkreis Bilanzkreis="11XGASAG-STROM-5">
        <ID ID="11XGASAG-STROM-5" />
    </Bilanzkreis>
    <Zaehlpunkt Zaehlpunkt="DE0000801230500000000000012520182">
        <ID ID="DE0000801230500000000000012520182" />
    </Zaehlpunkt>
    <Standardlastprofil__syn_ Standardlastprofil__syn_="HB">
        <Profil Profil="HB" />
        <Codeliste Codeliste="89" />
    </Standardlastprofil__syn_>
    <Zaehlverfahren Zaehlverfahren="E02">
        <Verfahren Verfahren="E02" />
    </Zaehlverfahren>
    <Haushaltskunde Haushaltskunde="Z15">
        <Haushaltskunde Haushaltskunde="Z15" />
    </Haushaltskunde>
    <Zaehlpunktdaten Zaehlpunktdaten="1">
        <Bezeichnung Bezeichnung="DE0000801230500000000000012520182" />
        <Jahresverbrauchsprognose Jahresverbrauchsprognose="2322">
            <Prognose Prognose="2322" />
        </Jahresverbrauchsprognose>
        <Zeitreihentyp__Z21_ Zeitreihentyp__Z21_="SLS">
            <Code Code="SLS" />
        </Zeitreihentyp__Z21_>
    </Zaehlpunktdaten>
    <Zaehler Zaehler="2">
        <Zaehlpunkt Zaehlpunkt="DE0000801230500000000000012520182" />
        <Zaehlertyp Zaehlertyp="Z30">
            <Nummer Nummer="31078265" />
        </Zaehlertyp>
    </Zaehler>
    <Kunde Kunde="Zozula">
        <Nachname_Firma Nachname_Firma="Zozula" />
        <Vorname Vorname="Octavian" />
        <Typ Typ="Z01" />
    </Kunde>
    <Lieferanschrift Lieferanschrift="Rackebüller Weg18">
        <Strasse Strasse="Rackebüller Weg" />
        <Hausnummer Hausnummer="18" />
        <Ort Ort="Berlin" />
        <PLZ PLZ="12305" />
        <Land Land="DE" />
    </Lieferanschrift>
</Vorgang>
```

So, for example, with the element Haushaltskunde, I cannot create the xsd file, and cannot continue with the generation of the class =(

Comment: i think you can make a commen class for this, but it is to specific. making a few extra classes is little work/ flexible / easy to understand and to maintain. So my recommandations is that this is the best way to go

Comment: Well, the main problem that I didn't comment, is that this will change every 6 months, so, actually I think the common class is the best way, but I don't have idea about how to do it.
Also, is not the whole xml, but is quite...huge, and make a class for each element...Will take days =(

Comment: Why not use `DateTime` as property type for that? Second (this is just for better readability): Why is the property called `ContractBegin`, just call it `Begin`, since you know the property resides within a contract...

Comment: If you have the xml its easy... `xsd examplefile.xml` => generates xsd file, `xsd file.xsd /classes` => give you a .cs file. And the xml looks badly formatted btw, are you in control of the xml?

Comment: @derape We´re not allow to modify the XML, could be DateTime, but, in practice we prefer Strings, cause sometimes, the change the format to that date also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you question is regarding `xml -> poco` and not the other way around it means that there does exist some kind of `xml` already, which means that you should not write the class by hand in the first place! (Unless there are some weird circumstances of course)

Do this in the visual studio command prompt:

```
xsd.exe yourexamplefile.xml
xsd.exe yourexamplefile.xsd /classes
```

And voila! Now you have an automatically generated `C#` class, which you can both serialize and deserialize to your hearts content.

Given your specific case though this didn't work since `xsd.exe` cannot handle recursive elements, but the tool [available here can](http://geekswithblogs.net/pedrorui/archive/2006/08/09/87480.aspx). Just use that one first and then use `xsd.exe` as normal to generate the `C#` classes.

Comment: You´re right with the existing XML, the problem is we are not allowed to modify this XML, we receive it, I've try to generate the class xsd, but I got an error in one of the xmlElement, I will edit my Answer, so you can take a look on the "Real" xml

Comment: @TareqB. Interesting, I've updated my answer with a solutions which worked for your example. Does it fulfill your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the time @flindeberg but still not working, following the steps I got the same error with the Haushaltskunde, if I deleted everything works perfectly, So I guess that the unique way to do that is with wrapping classes, and by hand..

Anyway thanks!

Comment: @TareqB. I got it working, I'm using your example actually. I removed the German y though (U with two dots), and you are using InferenceTool.exe to generate an xsd and then xsd.exe to generate the classes?

Comment: That was I did, use the InferenceTool.exe (Actually amazing tool) and then the xsd.exe but for me didn't work, maybe because I did'nt delete anything like caracters Ü. Anyway I tried with the generated class you give me and works perfectly.

Now I´m wondering if I can make a main class where I can call the xsd.exe and generated the class from there when I need it, also, the main functions to handle all this stuff, but this will come later haha. You were very helpful, Thanks again! =D